# Dynamic background image in React.js with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to make a react component that has a background image which is provided as a url by JSON. This JSON has multiple objects inside, one of which (let's call it `imgObj`) has the url in it (`imgObj.url`).

Now, I want to use that url for the background image, but fail miserably.

Here's what I'm kind of trying to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
    background-image: `url(${props => props.imgObj.url})` // this is where I think the problem is
`;

const Component = ({ imgObj, otherStuff }) => (
    <Container>
        {otherStuff}
    </Container>
);

export default Component
```

I tried couple of different variations of `background-image` line, but can't get it right.

I am using styled-components here but honestly, I'd be happy with any solution that works.

Comment: I think you have to pass props imgObj to Container <Container imgObj={imgObj}>

Comment: @Doppio You sir are correct!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else who want the solution, using styled-components

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
background-image: `url(${props => props.imgObj ? props.imgObj.url : 'PLACEHOLDERIMG.png'})` // this is where I think the problem is
`;

const Component = ({ imgObj, otherStuff }) => (
<Container imgObj> // <=== Here is where the problem actually is!
    {otherStuff}
</Container>
);

export default Component
```

The reason is that you forget to insert `imgObj` props to your Container styled-component. So the component don't know where find `props.imgObj`.

Comment: Dont forget to validate if you have `props.imgObj`. Imagine what happens if you have `imgObj` undefined

Answer (score 2):

I have not used `styled-components`,  but you can define the background image as inline style in react as below:

```
...
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${props.imgObj.url})`}} >
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got back ticks around your "background-image" value. Remember that styled-components generates actual CSS, so this won't generate a valid CSS value.

Also, I'd recommend you to add quotes around your URL to avoid bad surprises:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  background-image: url('${props => props.imgObj.url}');
`;
```

So all in all, don't forgot that it's actual CSS you're generating, don't forget semicolons if possible (although those are often autocompleted, if they're missing, and be wary of what you're interpolating :)

Comment: The problem is, when I write it like that I get an error: "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined".

Comment: Yes, that indicates that url is used as a function on the Ja side. So that’s most likely because you have those extra backticks. Then JS is going to assume that you’re *calling* url but you’d want it inside that tagged template string. Try my snippet and you’ll see that that’ll work just fine ;)

Comment: I did use your snippet. I even copied it to make sure I got it right, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

If `imgObj` will be undefined `background-image` will not be rendered at all.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.div`
  ${props => props.imgObj && props.imgObj.url && 
    `background-image: (${props.imgObj.url})`
  }
`

const Component = ({ imgObj, otherStuff }) => (
<Container imgObj={imgObj}>
    {otherStuff}
</Container>
)

export default Component
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a solution using typescript and styled components,

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface Props {
  imageUrl: string;
}

const Container = styled.div<Props>`
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.imageUrl});
`;
```